# How to add own CSS to includeded form in PHP

Tags: php, css, forms, overwrite

I have proxy server powered on PHProxy 0.5b2 where is included mini url form. But there is an problem with CSS. Every visited page overwrite and overlap my own CSS.

I tried to add own **style=""** for every object but is not working (visited sites overwrite css).

My index.inc.php

```
if ($_flags['include_form'] && !isset($_GET['nf']))
{
    $_url_form      = '<div style="width:100%;margin:0;text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #725554;color:#000000;background-color:#F2FDF3;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans,arial,sans-serif;padding:4px;">'
                    . '<form method="post" action="' . $_script_url . '">'
                    . ' <label for="____' . $_config['url_var_name'] . '"><a href="' . $_url . '">Address</a>:</label> <input id="____' . $_config['url_var_name'] . '" type="text" size="80" name="' . $_config['url_var_name'] . '" value="' . $_url . '" />'
                    . ' <input type="submit" name="go" value="Go" />'
                    . ' [go: <a href="' . $_script_url . '?' . $_config['url_var_name'] . '=' . encode_url($_url_parts['prev_dir']) .' ">up one dir</a>, <a href="' . $_script_base . '">main page</a>]'
                    . '<br /><hr />';

    foreach ($_flags as $flag_name => $flag_value)
    {
        if (!$_frozen_flags[$flag_name])
        {
            $_url_form .= '<label><input type="checkbox" name="' . $_config['flags_var_name'] . '[' . $flag_name . ']"' . ($flag_value ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . ' /> ' . $_labels[$flag_name][0] . '</label> ';
        }
    }

    $_url_form .= '</form></div>';
    $_response_body = preg_replace('#\<\s*body(.*?)\>#si', "$0\n$_url_form" , $_response_body, 1);
}
```

Any help?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: perhaps try to put !important next to the style you wish to force? http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/

Comment: I did it, but it does not work.

Comment: is your css code inline? normally inline code is stronger than included code.

Comment: I have CSS in style.css. Inline code it fix for 50% because if I have something like this: <input type="text"  placeholder="http://google.com" class="minipage" id="" autocomplete="off"> it will take css style from visited page like this: input, select, textarea {
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #eee inset;
color: #999;
font-family: 'Lora',serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-size: 1.4rem;
padding: 16px;
padding: 1.6rem;
width: 100%;
}

Comment: Is there any URL in which we can see the issue?

Comment: I love the way you spell *Includeded*

Comment: Here: [http://www.hideandgo.com] (http://www.hideandgo.com) @MarcoPrins: I maybe made some mistakes. But I'm only human.